# How '/' character can be escaped while parsing xml tag in an xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have "`<?xml version="1.0"?><nf:rpc xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:cdpd"xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="110"><nf:get><nf:filter type="subtree"><show><queuing><interface><ethernet><1/1/></ethernet></interface></queuing></show></nf:filter></nf:get></nf:rpc>]]>]]>`" content which I am passing on networking device named switch so that through this xml content, it could extract the command as mentioned in its tags like here command would be "show queuing interface ethernet 1/1".

But when I run this file, it shows error as "

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nf:rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <nf:rpc-error>
    <nf:error-type>application</nf:error-type>
    <nf:error-tag>invalid-value</nf:error-tag>
    <nf:error-severity>error</nf:error-severity>
    <nf:error-message>Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
id="110"&gt;&lt;nf:get&gt;&lt;nf:filter type="subtree"&gt;&lt;show&gt;&lt;queuing&gt;&lt;interface&gt;&lt;ethernet&gt;&lt;"
```

Anybody please tell how to escape this '/' in the tag or any work around for this.

Comment: It may be helpful to show a short Python code snippet that generates that error so that we can duplicate the issue you’re having. However, is there a reason that 1/1 needs to be a tag and not the content of the <ethernet> tag?

Comment: Yes, coz I am using this thing for netconf protocol and the requirement for that is like this only as mentioned here : "http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_2_1_s_v_1_4/xml_api/configuration/guide/n1000v_xml_api/n1000v_xml_api_3request.html". The code that is using thie xml as an input is: while line:
  child.send(line) # child.send(line + '\r')
         child.expect('</nf:rpc-reply>]]>]]>')
         line = fout.readline()

Comment: Also, I tried to use <ethernet 1/1> and <ethernet1/1> but giving same problem. Any workaround please

Comment: I looked through the page you’ve linked (not that you have an extraneous space on the end of the link that is causing it to 404), and found the same thing that tripleee did in their answer below. If that isn’t right, though, try to put the code sample in your question, using code formatting (just indent it so it is set off, as your error example is).

Comment: If now I have to use for this command, what should I do....<?xml version="1.0"?><nf:rpc xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:cdpd"xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="110"><nf:get><nf:filter type="subtree"><show><vlan><id><1/></id></vlan></show></nf:filter></nf:get></nf:rpc>]]>]]>
.As not parsing up for <1/>. I read that according to xml docs, number cannot be there in a tag so what should be done in tthis case??

Comment: Most likely you would do it the same way it asks for the interface: <id>1</id>. The final level appears to be the value, and the value is never—or at least shouldn’t be—the tag. (BTW, was your previous question answered by triplee? If so, consider marking it; otherwise, consider refining your question.)

Answer (score 1):

Your link is slightly broken but [the document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_2_1_s_v_1_4/xml_api/configuration/guide/n1000v_xml_api/n1000v_xml_api_3request.html) shows that some strings don't map 1:1 to XML tags.  For example, `version-error-does-not-exist` maps to `<version-error-doesnotexist>`.  So you really need to find out from the documentation how to transform your data into valid XML, not guess; there is no standard, universal, straightforward way to do what you ask.

There is an example on that page which maps `interface ethernet 2/30` into the following:

```
      <interface>
        <ethernet>
          <interface>2/30</interface>
        </ethernet>
      </interface>
```

so you're probably going to end up with something similar.  (I have abridged the output; there were description fields and other stuff I elided.)